# How to force text to stick in triangular size for html-email?

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

How should i go about forcing text to always stick inside of a particular form despite display size?

[image: Here is design example in question]

In this thingy half-transparent white triangle is a separate shape from background image and as it's obvious intent is to always have text stick inside.

Herein lies the question: what's a correct way to go about it? Are there any common practices for this?

How i'm intending to make it work right now: current idea is to make background and triangle overlay into one background picture and have a number of @media css rules for font sizes and paddings based on screen size, but i'm pretty sure that's not a correct way to go around it.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and update your question. In short: do not write an essay explaining what you want to do, **show your code** so we can see what have you have tried so far.

Comment: thanks for response! But this thing is the problem is exactly that i don't know how i should go about this issue besides directly bashing it in a head with @media conditions - is it really how it should be done?

Comment: You need to use VML and tables inside that. Then use media queries to control it in smaller devices. If you give it a start and get stuck let us know again